# Battle.net Mobile Authenticator won't initialize

Tags: battle.net

I'd like to attach a mobile authenticator to my World of Warcraft account for obvious reasons, but for some reason, it won't initialize. I installed it a few weeks ago and haven't been able to use it.

All the error text I see is

> ERROR
>   Check the reception in your area. If you have a signal, the server may be temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

It's persistent. I currently have full signal on my phone and it's also connected to my DSL line through the Wifi modem as well.

I'd be most grateful if anyone could help me out with this!

My phone is a Blackberry 8520 which I've confirmed is supported and the authenticator is available in my region

Comment: Did you try deleting the `authenticator` from your cell phone, installing it again and adding an `authenticator` to your profile once again with new info(authenticator code or whatever it is)?

Comment: I know this seems dry, that's why I put this in a comment. But just call Blizzard. They have all solutions for tech problems.

Answer (score 1):

There could potentially be three issues:

1. Is your phone [one of the supported mobile platforms?](https://us.battle.net/account/support/mobile-auth-download.html) If not, you'll have to buy an authenticator.
2. Where are you? The Blizzard Mobile authenticator is only available [in certain regions](https://us.battle.net/account/support/mobile-auth-download.html).
3. If you have a supported phone and are in a supported region, you could [try Resyncing or Restoring](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-mobile-authenticator-faq#q8) the mobile authenticator. Sometimes the serial number of the authneticator doesn't match your account and gets screwed up.

If none if these issues apply to you, contact Blizzard support directly.

Comment: None of this actually applies. I removed the authenticator from my account previously, but never deleted it from my phone. Stupidly, I did delete but now this. Only menu items in the authenticator app are "Retry" and "Exit" so can't resync or restore :/

Comment: Yea that would have been relevant info to include in your OP. Contact Blizzard support, clearly something got screwed up by your mistake of not removing the authenticator from your phone at the same time you removed it from your account. My suggestion is to remove everything (from account, phone, etc) and try it again from scratch.

Comment: heh well, don't really know what I'm doing here. Sorry about the sketchy info though

Comment: Still no luck... I've opened a ticket with Blizz though I might be an old man by the time they answer :(

Comment: Hahaha, don't worry, they'll usually get in contact within 24 hours. If not, try giving them a call. I've found calling them gets faster results, but you're put on hold for a while beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issues already mentioned:

The Mobile Authenticator also relies on an accurate clock on the device on which it is running. So, if [your phone's time or time zone is not correct](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/14928/The_time_on_my_device_is_incorrect_50_651963_11.jsp), the authenticator may not work.